# Opencart Multistore - Redirect one of the store to account/login

Tags: php, opencart

I use Opencart version 1.5.4.1, and I have installed store modules & have 3 stores (Example default, Store1, Store2) in the Dropdown.

My requirement is to redirect the last store (Example Store2) to `account/login`.

I tried to modify the path in `\catalog\controller\module\store.php` from `index.php?route=common/home` to `index.php?route=account/login` but both Store1 & Store2 are getting redirected to `account/login`.

I also tried using the below `if` condition: if I select from default to Store1 & Store1 to Store2, it's working, but if any select from default to Store2, it is not working.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if((int)$this->config->get('config_store_id')==1)
    {
        $this->data['stores'][] = array(
            'store_id' => $result['store_id'],
            'name'     => $result['name'],
            'url'      => $result['url'] . 'index.php?route=account/login'
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['stores'][] = array(
            'store_id' => $result['store_id'],
            'name'     => $result['name'],
            'url'      => $result['url'] . 'index.php?route=common/home'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `vqmod code`:

1. Copy it to a file with an `.xml` extension.
2. Upload it to `vqmod\xml` folder.
3. Store id is set to 1, change it if your store number is different.

---

```
<modification>
    <id>Force Customer Login</id>
    <version>152.1</version>
    <vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
    <author>Qphoria</author>
    <file name="catalog/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[function index()]]></search>
            <add trim="true">
                <![CDATA[//Q: Force Customer Login
                    $match = false;
                    if (!empty($this - > request - > get['route'])) {

                        $skip = array(
                            'payment',
                            'feed',
                            'forgotten',
                            'login',
                            'register', );

                        foreach($skip as $s) {
                            if (strpos($this - > request - > get['route'], $s) !== false) {
                                $match = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!$match) {
                        if (!$this - > customer - > isLogged()) {
                            if ($this - > config - > get('config_store_id') == 1) {
                                $this - > redirect($this - > url - > link('account/login', 'SSL'));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```